# Printing reduced form of division

Tags: java, eclipse, division

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      
      int[] y = division(230,6);
      System.out.println(y[0] + " " + y[1] + "/" + y[2])
      
   }

   private static int[] division(int nominator, int denominator) {
         int k = nominator / denominator;
         int r = nominator % denominator;
         int n = denominator;
         int[] arr = { k, r, n };
         return arr;
      }

}
```

the division of 230/6 will give me 38 + 2/6. I want to get 38 + 1/3, I want the fraction part in reduced form. I am not sure how to do it in java. Is there any simple way to get the fraction part in reduced form without using one of the inbuilt methods of java.

Comment: you can develop a method that find the  GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) of r and n. After that you divide r by the GCD also n ==> https://beginnersbook.com/2018/09/java-program-to-find-gcd-of-two-numbers/

Comment: `without using one of the inbuilt methods of java`... you surely did NOT mean what you said there, right? @jhdev nice answer

Answer (score 2):

You can develop a method that finds the GCD of `r` and `n` :

```
private static int findGCD(int num1, int num2) {
    while (num1 != num2) {
        if(num1 > num2)
            num1 = num1 - num2;
        else
            num2 = num2 - num1;
    }
    return num2;
}
```

in division method you can add this code :

```
int gcd = findGCD(r, n);
```

And replace

```
int[] arr = { k, r, n };
```

With :

```
int[] arr = { k, r/gcd, n/gcd };
```

Comment: Why do i return num2 and not num1?. I get the same value regardless if I return num2 or num1.

Comment: the While condition is num1 != num2, so it will stop when num1 == num2. Why this condition? it is a Math logic

Comment: so it doesn't matter if i return num1 or num2, i will still get the same value returned?